# Accessibility of main from agent's statechart

Tags: anylogic

May I know if main is accessible to all elements in the model?

The reason I ask is that I have created a simple M/M/n model with one resource type created through ResourcePool. The behaviour of the resource type is implemented using a statechart. I write a simple code in the action of a transition in the statechart, i.e.

`if (agent_variable < main.my_parameter) { /* do something */ }`

The code does not compile and give an error message "main cannot be resolved to a variable". I cannot figure out why the statechart cannot recognise main.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to SOF, Stephan.

First, always use code-complete (Ctrl+space). You will then see what is and what is not possible to access from where you are. In your case, `main` would not even be an option :-)

Now, your model root (typically that is `main`) is always accessible via `getModelRootAgent()` but you will need to cast it to your `Main` class, i.e.  `((Main)getModelRootAgent())`

Otherwise, `Main` is accessible to all agents that are somehow embedded into Main. This is classic OOP principles. Your Resource agents are not actually an embedded population so no direct access to Main. (You can make that happen in the ResourcePool properties, though)

Comment: Hi Ben, thanks for the pointer. I could not find getModelRootAgent() but I found getRootAgent() which seems to do the same purpose from your explanation. For the benefot of others, the following code works (while direct use of main does not in my case):

if (agent_variable > ((Main)getRootAgent()).a_parameter_in_the_main)
{
 // do something
}

Comment: true, didn't have AnyLogic open and just stated it from my memory. If you use code-complete, you will see its description as well